# outlet nil even though in the same controller

Tags: swift, function, uiview, uiviewcontroller, outlet

I have a navbar view controller with a subview, i am trying to call this function from the subview

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    selectedFavour = FavoursDataSet[indexPath.row].id

    subviewviewcontrollername = "FavourView"

    let storyboard: UIStoryboard =
        UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main",bundle: nil);

    let tabViewController: TabViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabView") as! TabViewController;
    wassubview = true

    tabViewController.showsubviewsubs()



}
```

which is calling the showsubviewssub() function which is this function

```
@IBOutlet var thecontentView: UIView!




func showsubviewsubs(){

    let previousVC = viewControllers[selectedIndex]

    previousVC.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
    previousVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
    previousVC.removeFromParentViewController()

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    subviewviewcontroller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"HomeView")

    let vc = subviewviewcontroller

    self.addChildViewController(vc!)
    vc?.view.frame = thecontentView.bounds
    thecontentView.addSubview((vc?.view)!)

    vc?.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

}
```

the problem is is thecontentView outlet (the view the subview that is calling this function is already in) returns nil even though i am calling it from that Viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

The IBOutlets will not be setup at that point.  You should move the call of `showsubviewsubs` into the 'HomeView' view controller itself because at that point you are guaranteed that everything has been setup.

It's also a much better practice to do this because then you don't rely on something external to the view controller being responsible for the setup getting done.

Comment: The IBOutlets should be set up at this point since the function is being called from a subview that is sub viewed in "thecontentview" outlet im just trying to load a different subview but cannot be done with on the same controller since it is done by selecting a cell on the subviewed controller

Comment: You create a new instance of your view controller in the local tabViewController variable and then immediately call its showsubviewsubs method.  You haven't added that view controllers view to anything and so nothing for it has been setup.

Comment: but how it works is to get to this area i have to click on a page which loads the tabviewcontroller up and then subviews another controller in it, then when you click a cell in that subview controller it needs to load up another subview in that already populated tabviewcontroller, the contentview is already populated before the cells are

Comment: oh i see, because i load up the navcontroller again so when the homeview has loaded it can then be subviewed into the the contentview?

Comment: but the tabViewController in that function is not the original one it is a brand new one you have created.  Doing this `let tabViewController: TabViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabView") as! TabViewController;` creates an entirely new copy of the view controller it does not refer to any currently existing one.

Comment: okay i see whats wrong is there a way to access the function from the subview without loading the viewcontroller again

Comment: Well you could pass a reference to the parent view controller to the sub view controller but that's not good practice.  A better way is to look into protocols and delegates and implement that kind of thing.

Comment: do you know of any reference to these would prefer to learn the delegate way if it is proper way of doing it

Comment: I just googled and this tutorial looks good: https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef